# What are the differences between is_signer AccountInfo property, Signer type and signer constraint

Tags: anchor, solana-program

what is the difference between `signer` constraint:

```
Checks the given account signed the transaction.
Custom errors are supported via @.
Consider using the Signer type if you would only have this constraint on the account.

Example:

#[account(signer)]
pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
#[account(signer @ MyError::MyErrorCode)]
pub payer: AccountInfo<'info>
```

and

```
pub struct AccountInfo<'a> {
    pub key: &'a Pubkey,
    pub is_signer: bool,
    pub is_writable: bool,
    pub lamports: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut u64>>,
    pub data: Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>,
    pub owner: &'a Pubkey,
    pub executable: bool,
    pub rent_epoch: Epoch,
}
```

is_signer property on AccountInfo?

`is_signer: bool Was the transaction signed by this account’s public key?`

and then we have also `Signer` type instead of `AccountInfo`

`pub struct Signer<'info> { /* private fields */ }`
Type validating that the account signed the transaction. No other ownership or type checks are done. If this is used, one should not try to access the underlying account data.

Answer (score 1):

The `is_signer` field in an `AccountInfo` struct indicates that the account has signed the transaction/instruction from the client. It can only be set client-side and the on-chain code checks this to see if it has rights.

Both `Signer<'info>` and `#[account(signer)]` do the same thing: They enforce that an account has actually signed the instruction from the client by ensuring that the `is_signer` field of the account is set to true.

The slight difference between both is that `Signer` is a wrapper around `AccountInfo` and essentially the same as:

```
#[account(signer)]
AccountInfo<'info>
```

This means that when you use it, you're stating that no other type checks are needed.

The `#[account(signer)]` attribute on the other hand is more flexible and can be used with different type checks and ownership constraints i.e:

```
#[account(mut, signer, has_one = ...)
Account<'info, State>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer . problem is that my account has signer constraint and still someone else could’ve drained funds out of it, so i think constraint is not doing what it should.

Comment: That's weird. The signer constraint in itself isn't enough for security though. You have to assert that the signer is also the expected authority.